# "bmake: no system rules (sys.mk)" when trying to build OS161 on Mandriva

Tags: linux, build, operating-system, makefile, os161

I'm TAing an Operating Systems class, and I'm trying to get a working install of Harvard's OS161 set up on our Mandriva lab machines.

I've got the toolchain set up, but when I try to build the source with bmake, I get the following error:

```
"bmake: no system rules (sys.mk)."
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm fairly sure it's a problem with the bmake install, not with the source itself.

Answer (score 4):

try to set the bmake flag manually 
$export MAKESYSPATH=~/os161/tools/share/mk/